# Check array for absolute value within plus or minus of specified number

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

How can I loop through this array and find out whether there is *at least one* value that is within plus or minus 250 of 0?  In other words, if there is at least one value that is anywhere from -250 to +250, then this is a positive result. Otherwise, return negative.

Here is the array (which should return a positive result because of the number -144):

```
Array
(
[Nov 18, 2011] => Array
    (
        [C] => -1738
    )
    (
        [I] => -144
    )
[Jan 13, 2012] => Array
    (
        [C] => -3193
    )
    (
        [M] => 4377
    )
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
foreach ($root as $data) {
    $positive = false;

    foreach ($data as $number) {
        if ($number >= -250 && $number <= 250) {
            $positive = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if ($positive)
        break;
}

if ($positive === true) ...
```

Comment: What's that `if ($positive) break;` doing in there?

Comment: Assuming the code is *not* in a function, `if ($positive) break;` prevents the script from iterating through any subsequent elements of the root array once it's found at least one number within the specified range. (The first instance of `break;` only breaks out of the 'sub-array'.) If this were placed in a function, the snippet could be simplified quite a bit.

Answer (score 2):

```
function containsDesiredValue($array){
    foreach ($array as $subArray)
        foreach ($subArray as $value)
            if (abs($value) <= 250)
                return true;
    return false;
}
```

assuming the structure of your array does not change.

Answer (score 2):

```
function check250($array) {
    foreach ($array as $lvl1)
        foreach($lvl1 as $num)
            if ($num <= 250 && $num >= -250) return true;
    return false;
}
```